# How to change JFrame input into an array

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, user-input

Right now I have a do-while loop to get grades that a user will enter. How would I convert the grades the user is entering into an array of grades?

```
private void enterGradesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
String grades1;
double grades;

grades1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Grades",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    grades=Double.parseDouble(grades1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the number of grades to be entered, store them in a list and at the end convert the list to an array.

Something like this:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (...){
    list.add(aGrade);
}
Double[] array = list.toArray(new Double[]{});
```

The other way is using an initial array, and if you reach the total lenght of it change the initial array for another array of greater size.

Comment: What would i do if my array can be no larger than 25?

Comment: Then use an array of size 25 and check the number of grades inserted previously to insert a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a collection up-front:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Then, in your loop, add the `grades` object to this list for each iteration

```
list.add(grades);
```

Finally, once the loop is done, convert your `list` reference to an array:

```
Double [] yourGrades = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);
```